# Mage Hand Legerdemain vs Fast Hands

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue

The [Arcane Trickster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/rogue#ArcaneTrickster) rogue's Mage Hand Legerdemain feature description states:

> - You can stow one object the hand is holding in a container worn or carried by another creature.
> - You can retrieve an object in a container worn or carried by another    creature.
> - You can use thieves' tools to pick locks and disarm traps at range.
>
> You can perform one of these tasks without being noticed by a creature if you succeed on a Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check contested by the creatures Wisdom (Perception) check.
>
> In addition, you can use the ***bonus action granted by your Cunning
> Action to control the hand***.

The [Thief](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/rogue#Thief) rogue's Fast Hands feature states:

> Starting at 3rd level, you can ***use the bonus action granted by your
> Cunning Action to make a Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check, use your
> thieves' tools to disarm a trap or open a lock***, or take the Use an
> Object action.

Are these two features basically the same thing, besides the fact that Mage Hand Legerdemain allows it to be done at a range of up to 30 ft?

Answer (score 10):

They're similar, but Mage Hand Legerdemain only allows you to control the hand using your bonus action, you would still have to use your action to cast the spell itself.  Fast Hands also allows you to make any Sleight of Hand check while Mage Hands will limit you to the three kinds of sleight of hand checks listed.

Answer (score 3):

They are very similar.

The Fast Hands feature is only available to Level 3 Rogues with the Thief archetype.

The Mage Hand Legerdemain feature is only available to Level 3 Rogues with the Arcane Trickster archetype.  You cannot use this if you cannot and maintain Mage Hand (anti-magic, can't provide the verbal or somatic component).

Ultimately, both of these type of Rogues can accomplish the same sort of task in slightly different ways.